# Infinite loop in ComponentDidUpdate

Tags: javascript, reactjs, infinite-loop

I need to translate from Russian to Spanish and change some info in my React state. To achieve it I wrote a function called "translateHelper" that looks like this:

```js
translateHelper() {
        let type = this.state.tipo; 
        switch(type) { //translating
            case 'Проектор':
                type = 'Proyector';
                break;
            case 'Манифестор':
                type = 'Manifestador';
                break;
            case 'Генератор':
                type = 'Generador';
                break;
            case 'Манифестирующий генератор':
                type = 'Generador Manifestante';
                break;
            case 'Рефлектор':
                type = 'Reflector';
                break;        
        }
        if (this.state.sexo === 'female' && type !== 'Generador Manifestante') { //changes depending on sex
            type = type + 'a'
        }
        else if (this.state.sexo === 'female' && type === 'Generador Manifestante') {
            type = 'Generadora Manifestante'
        }
        this.setState({ //updating state
            tipo: type
        })
    }
```

Problem appears when I try to call this function from ComponentDidUpdate. It throws error saying: "Maximum update depth exceeded". As far as I understand this happens bc of the infinite loop in ComponentDidUpdate. But I don't understand where it is as I set the break condition that looks like this:

```js
componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
        if (prevState.tipo !== this.state.tipo) { //my condition
            this.translateHelper();
        }
    }
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: If you add `console.log(prevState.tipo, this.state.tipo)` before `this.translateHelper()`, what do you see?

Comment: @cbr  ```console.log('prevstate '+ prevState.tipo, 'this.state '+ this.state.tipo)``` gives me ```prevstate Proyectoraaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa this.state Proyectoraaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa```

Comment: It would also be a good idea to add a default in you switch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed is caused in your `componentDidUpdate` method, when `translateHelper` is called, it modifies the `state`, causing it to be called again, and so on, since there is no stop mechanism. The `prevState.tipo !== this.state.tipo` check is not doing anything, u should check if `this.state.tipo` is not in `Spanish`, and that's when u should only run `translateHelper`. Because u keep feeding the results of your first translation:

```
Проектор -> Proyector -> Proyectora -> Proyectoraa -> Proyectoraaa
```

#### Edit:

Since the number of words finite, what u can do is check if the word was already translated, if it was translated, u don't need to translate again right?, for example:

```
const translatedWords = ['Proyector', 'Proyectora', ... ]

componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
        const isTranslated = translatedWords.includes(this.state.tipo);
        if (!isTranslated) { 
            this.translateHelper();
        }
    }
```

Comment: So the best practice would be to modify state something like this:
```this.state = {
   tipo: {
       tipoName: 'Генератор',
       notInSpanish: true
    }
}```
and then setState in translatehelper ```notInSpanish: false``` ?

Comment: no, the problem is in `if (prevState.tipo !== this.state.tipo)`. as long as it is `true`, it's going to keep running again. u should check if `this.state.tipo` is not `['Proyector', 'Proyectora', 'Manifestador', ...]`

Comment: and how should I do this?